# Error creating AWS CDK Dashboard - AttributeError: 'CwDashboardStack' object has no attribute 'QA'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cdk

Problem : I have to create Cloudwatch dashboard in Python using AWS cdk .
I want to use an existing Load balancer(QA-Env-Public-ALB)in order to create metric.
Error:

```
AttributeError: 'CwDashboardStack' object has no attribute 'QA'.
```

Any idea why Python is splitting the Loadbalancer name with '-' and then trying to find it.
Code-

```
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 as elb_v2,
    aws_cloudwatch as cw
)
from constructs import Construct

class CwDashboardStackStack(Stack):

def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    http_5xx_metric = self.QA-Env-Public-ALB.metric_http_code_elb(
            code=elb_v2.HttpCodeElb.ELB_5XX_COUNT
    )

    http_requests_metric = self.QA-Env-Public-ALB.metric_request_count(
            statistic="SUM"
    )

    http_response_times = self.QA-Env-Public-ALB.metric_target_response_time()

    load_balancer_widget = cw.GraphWidget(
            title="Load Balancer Metrics",
            height=8,
            width=12,
            left=[http_5xx_metric],
            right=[http_requests_metric]
    )

    http_response_widget = cw.GraphWidget(
            title="Response Times",
            height=8,
            width=12,
            left=[http_response_times]
    )

    cw.Dashboard(
            self,
            "Dashboard",
            dashboard_name="Service-Status",
            widgets=[
                [load_balancer_widget, http_response_widget]
            ]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding metrics for an existing load balancer you will need to create an object that references that existing load balancer using the `from_application_load_balancer_attributes` or `from_lookup` methods.

See here for details on the two methods mentioned: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2/ApplicationLoadBalancer.html

Example:

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_elasticloadbalancingv2 as elb_v2,
    aws_cloudwatch as cw
)
from constructs import Construct

class CwDashboardStackStack(Stack):

def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    load_balancer = elb_v2.ApplicationLoadBalancer.from_application_load_balancer_attributes(
        self,
        "ALB",
        load_balancer_arn="arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-2:123456789012:listener/app/my-load-balancer/1234567890123456/1234567890123456",
        security_group_id="sg-0xxx6"
    )

    http_5xx_metric = load_balancer.metric_http_code_elb(
            code=elb_v2.HttpCodeElb.ELB_5XX_COUNT
    )

    http_requests_metric = load_balancer.metric_target_response_time(
            statistic="SUM"
    )

    http_response_times = load_balancer.metric_target_response_time()

    load_balancer_widget = cw.GraphWidget(
            title="Load Balancer Metrics",
            height=8,
            width=12,
            left=[http_5xx_metric],
            right=[http_requests_metric]
    )

    http_response_widget = cw.GraphWidget(
            title="Response Times",
            height=8,
            width=12,
            left=[http_response_times]
    )

    cw.Dashboard(
            self,
            "Dashboard",
            dashboard_name="Service-Status",
            widgets=[
                [load_balancer_widget, http_response_widget]
            ]
    )
```

I haven't actually tested this code but it should be close to right. In addition one problem you had is having a hyphen in your variable name `QA-Env-Public-ALB` which is not allowed. https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_variable_names.asp

Comment: I tried both methods: from_application_load_balancer_attributes() and from_lookup() for importing existing LB but these methods return object of type " IApplicationLoadBalancer".Hence getting- 
AttributeError: '<class 'aws_cdk.Resource'>+<class 'aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2._IApplicationLoadBalancerProxy'>' object has no attribute 'metric_http_code_elb'

Answer (score 0):

I tend to default to boto3 in these cases. For example:

```
    elb_client = boto3.client("elbv2")
    gwlb_widgets = {}
    namespace = "AWS/GatewayELB"
    response = elb_client.describe_load_balancers(Names=gwlb_names)
    for gwlb in response["LoadBalancers"]:
        components = self.split_arn(
            gwlb["LoadBalancerArn"], arn_format=ArnFormat.SLASH_RESOURCE_NAME
        )
        lb_name = components.resource_name

        vpc_id = gwlb["VpcId"]

        metric = cloudwatch.Metric(
            namespace=namespace,
            metric_name="ProcessedBytes",
            dimensions_map={"LoadBalancer": lb_name},
            label=lb_name,
            statistic="Average",
            period=period,
            unit=cloudwatch.Unit.BYTES,
        )
        gwlb_widgets[vpc_id] = cloudwatch.GraphWidget(
            width=widget_width,
            height=widget_height,
            title=f"{lb_name} ProcessedBytes",
            left=[metric],
            left_y_axis=cloudwatch.YAxisProps(min=0),
        )
```